# What ever I write in edit text should display in my textview blank space?

Tags: android, android-edittext

For example, I have a sentence in textview.
 I am fetching the  sentence from JSON array from a URl.

```
       My name is ____ .
```

I have an edit text below it.

```
  Edittext:    ___write answer____
```

Where the user write the name ,it should reflect in the textview sentence.
  So the result would be like this.

```
          My name is John.


         Edittext:__John___
```

How to achieve this,any suggestions.

```
                      try {

            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results");


            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                Collections.reverse(mcq);


                Quiz_MCQ detailAll = new Quiz_MCQ();

                detailAll.setPs(jsonobject.getString("ps"));


                mcq.add(detailAll);
                Collections.reverse(mcq);


            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", "" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);


        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);

           txtview.setText((CharSequence) et);
```

I fetch the data and I am trying to set text of edit text at _____"blank space"of the text view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**replace()** it does not change the actual value of sentence ... it returns the replaced instance... so try it this way.. it works

```
    final String sentence = "My Name is ____";

    myTextView.setText(sentence);

    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            myTextView.setText(sentence.replace("____",s.toString()));
        }
    });
```

Comment: please be more descriptive

Comment: I tried it but it shows only one character @ParasJain

Comment: I Edited the original answer ... check it out @ShwetabhSingh

Comment: Working great  thanks   @ParasJain

Answer (score 2):

Add `TextWatcher` to your `EditText`:

```
yourET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if(!(s.toString().equals("")))
                    yourTV.setText( "My name is " + s.toString())
                   else{
                        else yourTV.setText("My name is ");
                     }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

please try below code:

```
String ans=et.getText().toString();

String s=textview.getText().tostring();
//Replace should be changed to "replace" to solve compile time error.
s=s.replace("____",ans);
textview.setText(s);
```

Comment: The textview I have already have some text and I only want to put the edittext data where it is _____.It may be anywhere in the sentence.@Vasant

Comment: take textview data in tmpstring object and use replace function and assign ans to replace place.it will works.

Comment: okay will try it @Vasant

Comment: I updated code above

Comment: Getting error for Replace cannot resolve method @Vasant

Comment: it should be replace

Comment: whats problem occur?

Comment: It get solved.. @Vasant

Comment: yes... by using "replace"@Vasant